# How to import vector matrix from file?

Tags: import

how can I import matrix of 3 dimentional vector from a txt file? I know how to import simple matrix of number, but I dont know how to import matrix of vectors and what type of data should be in my file.
I'm exporting data into .txt file in my C program. I used pattern like

```
 {numbers} {numbers}
```

and

```
{numbers}, {numbers}
```

but I dont get matrix imported in mathematica.

Comment: Give us an example of how the data is stored in the file. What format is the file, first of all?

Comment: @MarcoB I've edited my question and added some examples I used.

Comment: @Sergei Podlipaev I don't believe you understood what MarcoB was asking for. Is the contents of your text file 3.7,2.6<carriagereturn><newline> or is it 3.7<tab>2.6<newline> or is 3.7<space>2.6<space><carriagereturn> or is it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have flexibility in choosing your txt file data format, then you can work backwards.

Start by constructing the objects you want in Mathematica. For example, a list of vectors:

```
testObject=Tuples[{0, 1}, 3]
(*{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1},...,{1, 1, 1}}*)
```

Then export this into a text file with a convenient format (such as CSV):

```
Export["test.txt", testObject, "csv"]
(* file will look like: "0,0,0<CR><LF>0,0,1<CR><LF>0,1,0<CR><LF>..."*)
```

Now, if you format your C-program output like this txt file, it should be easy to import as follows:

```
Import["test.txt", "csv"]
```

Comment: Easier and better: `Export["test.csv"]` and `Import["test.csv"]`. _Mathematica_ will recognize the format from the file extension.